# resetting a pin using "&= ~ (1 << PINXX)"

Tags: avr

health warning: total beginner

why is this the standard method to reset a pin:

REGISTER_NAME &= ~(1 << PINXX);

rather than the straightforward:

REGISTER_NAME &= (0 << PINXX);

thanks in advance for time, answers & bibliographical hints

Comment: Nobody will understand that. It's a question for mind-readers.

Comment: The second method doesn't look straightforward, it looks like a complicated way of saying `REGISTER_NAME = 0` (which isn't the same as the first method)

Answer (score 2):

It need to be understood, what each sign means in

```
REGISTER_NAME &= ~(1 << PINXX);
```

1) **<<** - this is logical shift left. This means that number on left side is shifted left by number of binary position, which is in right side.

For example.  *1 << 5* means  *0b00000001* shifted left 5 times (while zeroes appears at right). i.e. result will be *0b00100000* == 32.

In other words, *1 << X* means "give a number, in which only bit #X is set, and other bits are zeros"

Ok. At this point you can see that *0 << anything* gives always zero,

2) **~** - this is bitwise negation. It is inverts value of every bit in every position in binary representation of the number.

I.e. *~0b00100000* (or *~(1 << 5)*) == *0b11011111*.

Concluding, ~(1 << X) means "give a number, in which all bits are set, except of bit #X, which is to became zero"

3) **&=** - this is assignment combined with bitwise AND. I.e. *X &= Y* is the same that *X = X & Y*;

4) **&** - this is bitwise AND. result of this operation is number, in which only that bits are set, which are set at same position in both operands, and zero otherwise.

That means, if particular bit in one of operands is set, then same bit in result will be equal to bit at same position of another operand. If this bit is zero in either operand, then same bit in result will be zero.

You can rephrase *X &= Y* in this way: "if a bit in Y is one, leave the bit at the same position in X unchanged (whatever it is - one or zero). If the bit in Y is zero, then clear the same bit in X."

As was said above, *~(1 << N)* gives a number where every bit is set, except of N. So *X &= ~(1 << N)* means "Clear bit #N, and remain all other bits unchanged".

Now you can see, that

```
REGISTER_NAME &= (0 << PINXX);
```

is nonsense, because it means "Clear all the bits". It is the same as *REGISTER_NAME = 0;*

**By the way**, if you are using assignment in this form:

REGISTER_NAME |= (0 << PINXX) | (1 << PINYY);

this doesn't mean "set bit PINYY, and clear bit PINXX", it means "set bit PINYY and do nothing with bit PINXX (as with all other bits)"

Answer (score 0):

first instruction will reset pin `XX`, second instruction will reset all the pins associated to that register

Answer (score 0):

Why would shifting a zero be more "straightforward"? That makes no sense at all, it's just 0 which when bitwise-anded would clear the entire register. Not at all what you want.

Remember that this:

```
REGISTER &= ~(1 << PIN);
```

means

```
REGISTER = REGISTER & ~(1 << PIN);
```

I.e. it will bitwise-and the register with a constant that has 1s in all positions except bit number `PIN`. In particular the `~` operator applies to the shifted value, not just to the `1`.

This has the effect of setting just that bit to 0, and not touching any others. Just what you want, which of course is why it's the code you always see used. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion happens because you've been given an inaccurate description of what's going on in the "standard" way.

I suspect you've been told that when you do this:

```
REGISTER_NAME &= ~(1 << PINXX);
```

it means "logically AND the pin at position `PINXX` with `~1`, that is, with 0".

But it doesn't mean that. What it actually means depends on how big the register is. I'm going to assume that it's 16 bits, and `PINXX` is 8.

Then what the standard way actually says is:

```
REGISTER_NAME &= ~(1 << 8)
```

or (assuming you have a compiler that accepts `0b` for binary numbers)

```
REGISTER_NAME &= ~(0b0000000100000000)
```

or

```
REGISTER_NAME &= 0b1111111011111111
```

That is, the command isn't operating on just one pin - it's operating on all of them. (Just the operation on everything but the pin you want to change is "logically AND with 1", which means it is left alone). The expression `~(1 << PINXX)` is just a way to construct a number that's all `1`s in the places you *don't* want to touch, and `0` in the spot you do.

Your proposed "simpler" version would be the equivalent of:

```
REGISTER_NAME &= 0b0000000000000000
```

Which would reset all the pins controlled by that register.

Comment: right. Thanks--the answers were so helpful I am wondering how I could have been so dumb not to have realized it.

Answer (score 0):

To *set* a bit, you `variable |= (1 << position)`. This will generate something like `0000100`, assuming `position = 2`.
To *unset* a bit, you do the reverse: you `AND` instead of `OR`, and the mask is the opposite of the other.

Assuming position = 2,

1. `1 << position`: `00000100` as before.
2. Reverse it with bitwise not (`~`): `11111011`.
3. Apply bitwise `AND`. If it's `11011100, for example, you get:

   `11011100 &`
      `11111011 =`
      `-----------`
      `11011000`
      `_____^____`

For the sake of purpose I assumed 8 bit values but the procedure has no changes with longer widths. It could seem a little hard the first times but, if you do the calculus yourself, the logic behind it should show up; it's math, after all.